# Subset sum problem where each number can be added or subtracted

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum, partition-problem

Given a set `A` containing `n` positive integers, how can I find the **smallest integer >= 0** that can be obtained using **all** the elements in the set. Each element can be can be either **added or subtracted** to the total.
Few examples to make this clear.

`A = [ 2, 1, 3]`

`Result = 0` (2 + 1 - 3)

`A = [1, 2, 0]`

`Result = 1` (-1 + 2 + 0)

`A = [1, 2, 1, 7, 6]`

`Result = 1` (1 + 2 - 1 - 7 + 6)

Comment: The minimum sum would be found by taking the smallest number, then subtracting all other numbers from it. Do you mean "closest to zero"?

Comment: I assume you mean "the smallest sum >= 0"?

Comment: This is equivalent to the usual [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: @RB @ChrisWue Yes, smallest sum >= 0

Comment: @Sven Marnach: *Weakly* NP-complete. It has a dynamic programming solution which is pseudopolynomial - O(poly(sum of numbers in the problem)).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using Boolean Integer Programming. There are several algorithms  (e.g. Gomory or branch and bound) and free libraries (e.g. LP-Solve) available.

Calculate the sum of the list and call it s. Double the numbers in the list. Say the doubled numbers are a,b,c. Then you have the following equation system:

```
Boolean x,y,z 

a*x+b*y+c*z >= s

Minimize ax+by+cz!
```

The boolean variables indicate if the corresponding number should be added (when true) or subtracted (when false).

**[Edit]**

I should mention that the transformed problem can be seen as "[knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)" as well:

```
Boolean x,y,z 

-a*x-b*y-c*z <= -s

Maximize ax+by+cz!
```